# how to use one of the options (flag) as an argument for another option (Apache.commons.cli)?

Tags: java

I am new to org.apache.commons.cli library and have a question.
Let's say I have two options -c and -r .

args = {"-c","apple","-r"}

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();

    Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption("c", "concatenate", true, "Concatenate Characters");
    options.addOption("r","reverse",false, "reverse characters");
    CommandLine commands = parser.parse(options, args);
    if (commands.hasOption("c")) {
        System.out.println("sentence: " + commands.getOptionValue("c"));
    }
}
```

So I expect output to be "sentence: apple" as an output.

My question here is what if args is {"-c","-r"}?
How can I make "-r" recognized as string like "apple" (not one of the options) so that the output is "sentence: -r"?

Comment: so according to my knowledge you can have `-r` as either value or argument but not as both, that will work if you have `-r` only as value

Comment: I'd like to have -r both for value and argument depending on the condition. If -c has value, -r is considedred arugument, if -c doeesn't have value -r is considered value. Can you write a condition to meet this situation?